# Qr code shows no usable data when scanned

Tags: python, qr-code, pysimplegui

```
import PySimpleGUI as psg
import qrcode
import os
import PIL

col_a = [
    [psg.T('QR IMAGE')],
    [psg.Image(key='-IMG-')],

]

layout = [
    [psg.T('Please enter your full name:'), psg.I(key='-name-', s=(20, 1), do_not_clear=True, pad=(35, 5))],
    [psg.T('Please enter your phone number:'), psg.I(key='-number-', s=(20, 1), do_not_clear=True, pad=(5, 10))],
    [psg.Radio('Male', "Radio", key='-male-'), psg.Radio('Female', "Radio", key='-female-')],
    [psg.I(key='-departure-', size=(25, 1)), psg.CalendarButton('Select Day Of Departure', close_when_date_chosen=True,
                                                                target='-departure-', location=(10, 10),
                                                                no_titlebar=False)],
    [psg.LB(values=['Accra', 'Kumasi', 'Cape Coast', 'Takoradi', 'Tamale', 'Ho', 'Koforidua'], size=(40, 5), pad=(5, 5),
            select_mode='single', key='-destination-')],
    [psg.B('Reserve Ticket'), psg.B('Check Reservations'), psg.Exit()],
    [psg.HSep()], [psg.Col(col_a)]

]

reservations = []

window = psg.Window('Bay Transports', layout)


def inputformat(values):
    information = 'Ticket Booked!'
    name = '\nName: ' + values['-name-']
    information += name
    number = '\nNumber: ' + values['-number-']
    information += number
    gender = '\nGender: '
    if values['-male-']:
        gender += 'Male'
    else:
        gender += 'Female'
    departure_time = '\nDeparture Time: ' + values['-departure-']
    information += departure_time
    destination = '\nDestination: ' + values['-destination-'][0]
    information += destination

    return information


def reservation_list(values, reservations):
    return reservations.append(inputformat(values))


def qrcode_gen(information):
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        box_size=5,
        border=5,
        version=1
    )
    qr.add_data(information)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image(fill='black', back_color='white')
    file_name = 'Qr' + '.png'
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file_name)
    img.save(path)
    return path


while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (psg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == 'Reserve Ticket':
        reservation_list(values, reservations)
        psg.popup(inputformat(values))
        cde_qr = qrcode_gen(information=values)
        qr_image_path = qrcode_gen(cde_qr)
        window['-IMG-'].update(filename=qr_image_path)
    elif event == 'Check Reservations':
        psg.popup(reservations)
    '''elif event == 'Generate':
        cde_qr = qrcode_gen(inputformat(values))
        qr_image_path = qrcode_gen(cde_qr)
        window['-IMG-'].update(filename=qr_image_path)'''
window. Close()
```

My project is to create a program that can be used to make reservations for buying bus tickets using PySimpleGui. The program works till it gets to the point where I have to generate a QR code that shows reservation details. When I scanned the code, the result was "no usable data found". I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. The whole code is what I posted above.

Comment: It looks like an iOS error message. Have you tried another phone or scanning your qrcode online ?

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal in VSCode from View -> Terminal and run following:

```console
pip install PySimpleGUI
pip install qrcode
pip install --upgrade
pip install --upgrade pip
```

and

```console
pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

[image: Screenshot of VS code]